# How to catch leaving focus from active window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, messaging

I have window with CTabsCtrl - with child window.
I need to catch situation, when user leave rigth window (window with brown border and blue background) and click to ctreectrl on the left (marked with yellow border).
I tried WW_LOST_FOCUS but it doesn't work.

How to do it?

(I need to save value in right window since user change item in CtreeCtrl)

Thanks for help.[image]

Comment: Handle it in treeview change instead...

Comment: [WM_KILLFOCUS is the wrong time to do field validation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040419-00/?p=39753).